# How to filter rows based on data from multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have mySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `device` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `property` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(200));
```

that contains data like:

```
1, 1, 'code', '123'
2, 2, 'code', '12345'
3, 1, 'old_code', '987'
4, 3, 'code', '12345'
5, 2, 'old_code', '12345'
```

I need to get a list of devices where 'code'<>'old_code'.
I think it should be doable, but my mind can't get around it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you need

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**

Comment: Correct answer would be device=1, as this one has code=123 and old_code=987.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 
  device
FROM
(
   SELECT 
     device,
     MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'code'     THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS Code,
     MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'old_code' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS old_code
   FROM inventory
   GROUP BY device
) AS t
WHERE code <> old_code;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/611ce/1)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. My small brain couldn't quite compose it at the end of a day :)

Answer (score 3):

Using a self-join:

```
SELECT   new.device
FROM     inventory AS new 
    JOIN inventory AS old
      ON old.device = new.device
     AND old.property = 'old_code'
     AND new.property = 'code'
WHERE    new.value <> old.value
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e753f/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

Try self join

```
select a.* from inventory as a join inventory as b on a.device=b.device 
where a.property='code'
and b.property='old_code' and a.value!=b.value
```